# How can I write this code more efficiently to make it run faster?

Tags: python-3.x

The function of the code is to transform the dataset such that for each given pair of movies, it counts the number of users that have seen both movies and keep track of that value(store it as a column value).

I have tried writing the code as such but it takes a lot of time to execute when the pairs increase.

```
def dataset_to_item_graph(self):
    self.dataset1=self.dataset
    items=self.dataset['movieId'].unique()
    print(len(items))
    ux=combinations(items,2)

    item_edges=[]
    for x in ux:
        i = x[0]
        j = x[1]
        a = set(self.dataset1.loc[self.dataset1['movieId'] == i]['userId'])
        b = set(self.dataset1.loc[self.dataset1['movieId'] == j]['userId'])
        c = a.intersection(b)
        if len(c) >0:
            edge_list=[i,j,len(c)]
            item_edges.append(edge_list)
        else:
            continue

    item_graph = pd.DataFrame(item_edges, columns=['movie1','movie2','weight'])

    return item_graph


This is the sample dataset I am working with:      
        userId  movieId  rating  timestamp
     0       1        1     4.0  964982703
     1       1        3     4.0  964981247
     2       1        6     4.0  964982224
     3       1       47     5.0  964983815
     4       1       50     5.0  964982931
     5       2        1     3.0  964982931
     6       2        3     4.0  964982831
     7       2        6     4.0  964982933
     8       3        47    5.0  964981249
     9       3        1     2.0  964981248
    10       3        50    3.5  965982931


This is the output I am expecting:
        movieId1  movieId  sum
     0         1        3    2
     1         1        6    2
     2         1       47    2
     3         1       50    2
     4         3        6    1
     5         3       47    1
     6         3       50    1
     7         6       47    1
     8         6       50    1
     9         47      50    2
```

Comment: I don't have time to code and test now, but I'm thinking it might help to do a `groupby` on `movieId`, then map those to a set of users, which should move upfront a lot of the filtering costs; then do combinations on movies, and users for movie should now be quickly accessible (for a very fast intersection + count)

Comment: Am pretty new to python coding, if you could write the code when you are free to help me understand, I will be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is that big for loop. It could be interesting to launch subprocesses to compute those steps in parallel instead of sequencially. Do you know the multiprocessing module? You could try looking at [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/multiprocessing-python), especially the example at the end, that uses `from multiprocessing import Queue`.